# How to avoid shift/reduce conflict with a production of several operands

Tags: c++, bison

For a simple language defining graphs, I'm having the following conflicting rule:

```
  rm_arcs: RM ARC VARNAME VARNAME ref_exp ref_exp 
    {
      $$ = new RmArcNodes($3, $4, $5, $6); 
    }
  | RM ARC VARNAME ref_exp ref_exp 
    {
      $$ = new RmArcNodes($3, $4, $5); 
    }
```

Which bisons says it causes 3 shift/reduce conflicts.

The `ref_exp` rule is defined as follows:

```
ref_exp : STRCONST
          {
            auto symbol = string_table($1);
            $$ = new StringExp(symbol);
          }
        | INTCONST
          {
             auto symbol = id_table($1);
             $$ = new IntExp(symbol);
          }
        | VARNAME
          {
            auto varname = var_tbl($1);
            if (varname == nullptr)
              {
                stringstream s;
                s << "var name " << $1 << " not found";
                $$ = new ErrorExp(s.str());
              }
            else
              $$ = varname;
          }
;
```

Is there any simple way for rewriting the grammar in order to eliminate these conflicts and without modifying the language?

Regards

Comment: I assume that `ref_exp` can include `VARNAME`?

Comment: @Puppy yes, that's right

Comment: Actually I just misread the grammar. I think that you can factor this out but don't remember how offhand.

Comment: Just I edit the question and I added the production `ref_exp`, in case it helps to improve the context

Comment: VARNAME is a token, right?

Comment: Yes. VARNAME is a token giving a var identifier

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should be able to do this by simply explaining to Bison more clearly what you want. Add a `ref_exp_without_varname` production (implementation obvious).

Then change

```
rm_arcs: RM ARC VARNAME VARNAME ref_exp ref_exp 
   | RM ARC VARNAME ref_exp ref_exp
```

into

```
rm_arcs: RM ARC VARNAME ref_exp_without_varname ref_exp
       | RM ARC VARNAME VARNAME ref_exp
       | RM ARC VARNAME VARNAME ref_exp ref_exp
```

I believe this should be the same but without conflicts, as I explicitly disambiguated the 4th entry.

Comment: Your answer didn't show up in my browser until after I'd added mine, which surprised me when it did appear.  There's something slightly funny going on with SO caching/refreshing/detecting answer/comments.  Nice work; it does the trick.

Comment: Puppy Just a note to tell you that I just fixed the problem. I used your idea. Thank you (and @Jonathan too)

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that after the grammar has read `RM ARC VARNAME` and it receives another `VARNAME`, it doesn't know which rule to work with, leading to the shift reduce conflict.

One way to work around it is:

```
%token RM ARC VARNAME STRCONST INTCONST

%%

rm_arcs:
        RM ARC VARNAME ref_exp_list
    ;

ref_exp_list:
        VARNAME
    |   ref_exp_list ref_exp
    ;

ref_exp:
        STRCONST
    |   INTCONST
    |   VARNAME
    ;
```

This allows an arbitrary number of `ref_exp` values after the first VARNAME, but the first of those values must be a VARNAME.  You'd have a semantic action to limit the length of the list (so `RM ARC VARNAME VARNAME INT_CONST INT_CONST INT_CONST` would be rejected).

Comment: Even better would be `rm_arcs: RM ARC ref_exp_list` and `ref_exp_list: ref_exp | ref_exp_list ref_exp`, and do semantic checks for correctness of the list, as this generaly will result in much better error messages (rather than just `Syntax error`)

Comment: @ChrisDodd: there was a good reason for the 'one way to work around it' qualifier in my answer, even before I saw the other answer — and your suggestion also has merit and is another way to do it.